# Set jquery autocomplete width relative to textbox

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-autocomplete

I have several autocompletes on a form with varying text boxes, so I attempted to refactor the autocompletes. It worked... except for one small very annoying detail.

My textboxes are both percentage based widths, different sizes, and in bootstrap structure using class = "row" along with "col-md-9" to layout the page. Long story short: different sizes and not preset width.

Why is this a problem? Not setting the width to ul-autocomplete means it does initially try to match the element, but the minute a result is 'wider' than the box it expands. Most research indicates setting the weight is easy, just assing weight: ?px in the css. Obviously I can't do that. So what are my options?

My jquery if needed:

```
$('*[data-autocomplete-url]')
        .each(function () {
            var ddl = $(this);
            $(this).autocomplete({
                dataType: 'json',
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.get((ddl.data("autocomplete-url")), { phrase: request.term }, function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Text,
                                value: item.Value,
                                id: item.Value
                            };
                        }));
                    });
                },
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    ddl.val(ui.item.label);
                },
                change: function (event, ui) {
                    if (!ui.item) {
                        ddl.val("");
                    }
                },
                autoFill: true,
                mustMatch: true,
                minLength: 4,
            });
        });
```